# How to reduce the number of attributes to 20 using prcomp in R?

Tags: r

I have a 104 attribute dataset called `data`. I want to reduce the number of attributes to 20 using `prcomp` function in R.

I did this:

```
pr = prcomp(data)
```

But `pr` only contains an instance of the `prcomp` class. How do I reduce the number of attributes in the original dataset to 20?

Comment: Are you trying to reduce your data to 20 principal components, or do you just want to use 20 variables in the (final) analysis?

Comment: I just want 20 variables. But somebody told me that principal components represent all the different ways data can vary. So I thought, might as well use it to reduce the dimension.

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1576/what-are-the-differences-between-factor-analysis-and-principal-component-analysis

Answer (score 7):

First of all, prcomp does a principal component analysis. A principal component analysis makes as many components as there are variables. What you're looking for, is a factor analysis:

```
ff <- factanal(data,20)
```

see `?factanal`

If you want to keep only the first 20 principal components as a new dataset, you can easily select them from the predict() function. Or even calculate them yourself :

```
x <- prcomp(USArrests, scale = TRUE)

tt <- predict(x) # the standard way

# below the matrix way
tt2 <- scale(USArrests,x$center,x$scale) %*% x$rotation

# with only 3 components instead of 4
tt3 <- predict(x)[,1:3]
tt4 <- scale(USArrests,x$center,x$scale) %*% x$rotation[,1:3]
```

But be aware of the fact that a factor analysis reducing your dataset to 20 factors is NOT the same as keeping the first 20 principal components of a PCA.

Comment: In the `prcomp` function call, if I set the `tol` variable such that only 20 principal components are selected, and if I set the `retx` as TRUE, and access the `x` member of the return object, would that work too? I have done that and got 20 attributes instead of 104.

Comment: @louzer: There is no automated way in putting the tolerance level as to get a specific number of principal components. It is to cut out PC with a sd lower than a specific value. Tol is most commonly set at 1. Apart from that, this doesn't change the PC, contrary to `factanal`. So you don't get 20 components, you get 104 and ignore the last 84. That is something completely different. Please read in first on the differences between principal components and factor analysis. If you use the retx=T, then you can forget about tol and just do `pr$x[,1:20]`, similar to tt3 in my example.

Comment: I see. Thanks. I will try factor analysis too. I just want 20 dimensions instead of 104, so as to do an approximate k-nearest neighbor search in a computationally feasible manner. I use that technique on every member of the my dataset to find true negatives which are most similar to true positives. This is because my raw dataset has a 100 times more true negatives than true positives. I want the number of instances in the positive dataset and the negative dataset to be the same, so as to make the SVM training possible on a desktop.

Comment: @louzer: You could try stats.stackexchange.com for a more in depth discussion of the statistical reasoning behind your approach. I'm not completely following what you want to do, but I'm positive there is a bunch of people that can give you some good advice and different approaches to the problem.

Comment: @louzer If you only want this, it is better just to select random number of objects than to mess with attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Joris Meys' answer, but I thought I would add that `prcomp` has a `rank` parameter that allows one to select the first `n` principal components.

For example, to select the first 20 principal components one could use:

```
pca <- prcomp(data, rank = 20)
```